# ERROR : cannot open file 'worker' : No such file or directory with faust hello_world eg

Tags: python-3.x, faust

I am trying to follow faust [hello_world][1] example to work on my Mac. And getting below error:

```
$ faust -A hello_world worker -l info
ERROR : cannot open file 'worker' : No such file or directory
```

to my amaze below errors out as well.

```
$ faust worker --help
ERROR : cannot open file 'worker' : No such file or directory
```

```
$ faust --version
FAUST Version 2.20.2
Embedded backends:
   DSP to C
   DSP to C++
   DSP to FIR
   DSP to Interpreter
   DSP to Java
   DSP to LLVM IR
   DSP to old C++
   DSP to Rust
   DSP to SOUL
   DSP to WebAssembly (wast/wasm)
Build with LLVM version 9.0.0
Copyright (C) 2002-2019, GRAME - Centre National de Creation Musicale. All rights reserved.
```

1. macOS: Catalina
2. python3.7

NOTE: I was able to install kafka and able to run zookeeper and kafka. But I feel like this is not related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what the results of `which faust` are? it seems like you have some other thing using `faust` as a name. I specifically believe you are somehow accidentally calling [this faust](https://github.com/grame-cncm/faust) instead of the python kafka framework. The giveaway is there is no 2.X.Y for Robinhood's faust.